# text font and size for css liquid

Tags: css, text, fonts

I can't figure out how to manually change the text font and text size for my website (a small sale banner that runs beneath my homepage slide show). I want the sale banner to stand out, but I'm unsure of what commands to use and where to put them. The website uses a CSS Liquid format. I'm a techie newbie and am still learning the lingo. Be gentle.

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend throughly reading through these [beginner tutorials](http://www.htmldog.com/).

Font size is controlled with the `font-size` property.

So an example would be:

```
 .banner {
      font-size:36px;
 }
```